# Postgres Count Function

Tags: postgresql, count, crosstab

I have a table in Postgres with several columns.  For purposes of this question, I'll just say there are 2 columns, Employee ID and Date.  I have a sample below.

```
ID     |   DATE
F1     |   01/31/15
F2     |   01/31/15
E1     |   01/31/15
E2     |   01/31/15
F1     |   02/28/15
F2     |   02/28/15
E1     |   02/28/15
E2     |   02/28/15
```

You'll notice that I have 4 employees.  2 are "F" class employees, and 2 are "E" class employees.  I have records for the months of January and February that I want to count.

I'd like to count in such as way so that the query will separate month and year for me (I'm thinking something like

```
select to_char("Date", 'Mon') as mon,
       extract(year from "Date") as yyyy)
```

and count the F and E for me as different columns, so that I return results like this:

```
 mon   | yyyy | F | E |
January| 2015 | 2 | 2 |
Februar| 2015 | 2 | 2 |
```

Comment: Is the problem in extracting the month and year from the date?

Comment: Oh, no.  I was just using that as an example of what I was trying to get as a result

Comment: @Piechartking: did you tried the answer which i have given?

Comment: Oh yes, I did.  It worked well.  Thanks.  I had to modify a little bit because I simplified my example for posting clarity, but it worked great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this:

```
select to_char("date", 'Mon') as mon,
extract(year from "date") as yyyy ,
sum(case when l_part='E' then count end) as "E",
sum(case when l_part='F' then count end) as "F"
from(
     select left(id,1)as l_part, count(*),"date" from 
      table1 group by "date",l_part
   ) p group by "date";
```